# Is the Arch of Titus mentioned by Chazal?

Tags: sources-mekorot, yerushalayim-jerusalem, churban-destruction, archaeology, menorah--in-temple

Is there any mention in Rabbinic sources (whether by the Tanaim, Amoraim, Rishonim, Achronim) about the [Arch of Titus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_of_Titus)?

Comment: I saw a sicha recently in pashas teruma, I think it was around volume 30 something, that talked about how on the arch of titus they had the menorah with round branches, and that it was used to pain the jews etc., and it brought more sources in the notes there but I dont remember what they were [and earlier it proved that the branches of the menorah must have been square, as we recently found the drawing that the rambam made along with the testimony from his son r' avraham, and according to Rashi as well its clear they were straight

Comment: @Yaakov5777 Likutei Sichos Vol 21 page 168

Comment: @ezra nice, close enough to "in the 30s" :)